# What to do if Magick don`t load saved weapon?

Tags: magicka

I played with my friends for 2 hours and when we booted up again we saw that the items were not saved and my M60.

What should I do,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to preserve a weapon in Magicka within a saved multiplayer game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95231/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-a-weapon-in-magicka-within-a-saved-multiplayer-game)